# Problem with Creating a Prime Factor List (Edit: Title should say 'Factor List', not 'Prime Factor List')

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I'm new to Python and struggling with a coursework challenge. I need to use a loop function to list all factors of a given number (not including 1 and the number itself). Here's what I've got so far...

```
def factors(n):
    factors = []
    for i in range(2, n):
        while i < n:
            if n % i == 0:
                factors.append(i)
            return factors



print(factors(15)) # Should print [3, 5] to the console
print(factors(12)) # Should print [2, 3, 4, 6] to the console
print(factors(13)) # Should print “[]” (an empty list) to the console
```

By my reckoning, this should be create an empty list, then iterate through range specified by `print(factors(n))`, and add any prime factor to the list. However, it comes out as:

```
[]
[2]
[]
```

I though this was something to do with the iteration stopping when the function returned, so I added the `while i < n:`, but this doesn't seem to make a difference. In addition, I'm not allowed to edit the `print(factors(n))` call at the bottom.

I'd be extremely grateful if someone could explain this to me.

Thank you in advance!

edit: changed wording 'prime factors' to 'factors'

Comment: For `i < n`, surely `while i < n:` is an infinite loop. But -- you `return` from the overall function instantly. The logic seems a bit convoluted. Drop the while loop and don't return until the main loop is actually finished. Pay attention to levels of indentation.

Comment: Can you explain to us in plain English what your function does, step by step (what it actually does, not what it's supposed to do!), that might help you figure out the problem as well as the solution.

Comment: Question about this -  `factors(12)` -> it should give [2, 3] only!   Not other numbers, as 4, 6 are `not Prime`?   And factors(13) -> should be [13] itself?    (it all depends what's the req.)

Comment: You should edit the title of your question to remove the word `Prime`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's do a code review. Some of your issues are minor and some major:

```
(1)def factors(n):
(2)    factors = []
(3)    for i in range(2, n):
(4)        while i < n:
(5)           if n % i == 0:
(6)                factors.append(i)
(7)            return factors
```

First, in line 2 you create list named `factors`, which happens to be the name of your function, hiding your function definition. This would prevent your being able to recursively call your function from within your function if you needed to, which you don't in this case. But there is really no need for this. Let's call this a minor issue.

Second, all prime factors are going to be odd except for the possibility of the number 2 being a prime factor. Yet in line 3 you are testing all integers 2, 3, 4, ... n-1 to see if they are possibly prime factors when all the even numbers except for 2 cannot possibly be. The other numbers may be factors, but they are not necessarily prime. This is a major issue.

Third, given that line 3 assigns successively to `i` values 2 through n-1, there is no point including line 4: `i` has to be less than `n`. This is another minor issue.

Fourth, line 7 issues a `return` statement after having only examined the first value of `i`, which is 2. You have this statement at the wrong indentation level. This is another major issue.

A solution:

```
def prime_factors(n):
    factors = []
    while n >= 2 and n % 2 == 0:
        factors.append(2)
        n //= 2
    i = 3
    while i * i <= n:
        if n % i == 0:
            n //= i
            factors.append(i)
        else:
            i += 2
    if n > 1:
        factors.append(n)
    return factors
```

Note that this will return duplicates. That is, it will give you *all* the prime factors of a number so that the product of these factors yield the original number. It was not clear from your question whether this is desirable. But in your question you seem to think that the prime factors of 12 should be 2,3,4,6. They are not. They are 2,2,3.

**Update**

To just print factors using the corrections I pointed out:

```
def factors(n):
    the_factors = []
    for i in range(2, n):
        if n % i == 0:
            the_factors.append(i)
    return the_factors

print(factors(15)) # Should print [3, 5] to the console
print(factors(12)) # Should print [2, 3, 4, 6] to the console
print(factors(13)) # Should print “[]” (an empty list) to the console
```

Prints:

```
[3, 5]
[2, 3, 4, 6]
[]
```

Comment: This is a really helpful answer - although I've realised I've made a mistake in the use of the term 'Prime Factors' when I just meant 'Factors". I checked my post over 5 times for mistakes, but I've been sat in front of the screen since this morning. Apologies.

Comment: I've updated the answer to just print the factors with some of the corrections I had suggested (not all are now relevant).

Comment: Thanks for this, I understand it now. You've been very helpful. I've upvoted your post, but this is a new account, so votes are recorded but don't show publicly yet.

Answer (score 0):

Since your requirement is questionable (as the earlier posts asked), so I've tried to write this solution based on the strict `Prime` factors definition here.  You could try it and make adjustment based on the req.

```
def all_prime_factors(n):
    ''' given an positive integer - find its prime factors.

    >>> all_prime_factors(12)
        [2, 3] 
    '''
    i = 2   # starting with first prime
    result = []

    while i * i <= n:
        if n % i:   # non-divisible
            i += 1
        else:
            result.append(i)  # divisible
            n //= i

    result.append(n)          # rest n should be.
    return list(set(result))  # remove duplicates


if __name__ == '__main__':
    nums = [12, 13, 15,  17, 35] 

    for n in nums:
        print(f' number {n} has -prime factors: {all_prime_factors(n)}')
```

Comment: This is more efficient - it just store the candidates and not wasting extra space.

Comment: Thank you! Although I've made a mistake in asking for prime factors, I just meant factors. Apologies, although I think I understand now. I will try again tomorrow when I'm back in from of the computer.

Comment: @fsr023 - OK, If you run into another issue, welcome come back for help. If you find one of the posts is helpful, please select and upvote it.  People do take their time to help and deserve  acknowledgment. ...

Comment: @danielhao - Thanks very much. I've upvoted all of the posts, this is a new account so my upvotes are recorded but not publicly displayed.

Answer (score 0):

The function below first creates a list of prime number smaller than n, then iterates through those numbers to extract the prime factors of n:

```
def factors(n):
    primes = []
    for i in range(2, n):
        is_prime = True
        for m in range(2, i):
            if i % m == 0:
                is_prime = False
        if is_prime:
            primes.append(i)

    prime_factors = []
    for prime in primes:
        if n % prime == 0:
            prime_factors.append(prime)
    return prime_factors

print(factors(15))
#prints: [3, 5]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, this is great. Although I've realised I've made a mistake in asking for 'prime factors' instead of just 'factors'. I will try and re-work the code tomorrow!

Comment: Ok.  That's a much easier problem and requires a single for loop.  Make sure you upvote all the people who tried to help you with your original question.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've upvoted, but this is a new account, so votes are recorded but don't show publicly yet.